# Is there a way to create a context in python to not have to explicitly having to bind values?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write an application that extends a popular website right now. In it, you need to specify a person's username to get their information. Is there a way to make the code pass that data without having to explicitly specify it?

```py
def get_top_songs():
    username = get_username_from_context()
    return top_songs_api_fetch(username, "all-time")

with UsernameContext(username='james') as ctx:
    songs = get_top_songs()
```

I know that this can be done with globals, but if I want other people to be able to use it, then something like the following solution doesn't really work.

```py
username = ""

class UsernameContext():
    def __init__(self, username):
        self._username = username

    def __enter__(self):
        global username
        username = self._username

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        global username
        username = ""

def get_username_from_context():
    global username
    return username
```

Comment: What's the benefit to not explicitly passing values? e.g. `def get_top_songs(username): return ...` then `songs = get_top_songs('james')`? Beware the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). You can [edit] to clarify. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips. Thanks for providing code examples and writing clearly!

Comment: There seems to be a typo in the title. Should probably be "Is there a way to create a context in python to not have to explicitly bind values?"

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't just write a more simple class which stores the username as attribute and has a `get_top_songs` method which uses it.

Comment: For a single threaded application without use of async mechanism, it can be done with a global variable if the context remembers the previous value of the variable and restores it on exit. For multi-threading or async there are `threading.local` and `contextvars` respectively instead of a global variable.

Comment: For *testing* purposes, you would use `unittest.mock.patch` to patch the value of `get_username_from_context` to provide a hard-coded value. For numerous reasons, wjandrea's suggestion is the way to go. If you wanted to define a `UsernameContext` construct, you would still pass `ctx` to the function so it knew *which* context to pull an value from. But that's just adding a layer of complexity to an ordinary argument.

Comment: @wjandrea I think that is what I'm going to do, because then we only have to insert the value once and then it's also easier to test that way.